# How to add returned values from a Supplier to a FutureList

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

i want to run the three methods posted below using `CompletableFuture` asynchronous supplier so that, when the Executor finishes the `Futurelist` should contain three values returned from the three methods respectively.
i know how to use the `Futurelist`, for an example:

```
futureList = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()
```

but in my case, i want something like:

```
futureList.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync())
```

please let me know how can i do that.

**methods**:

```
this.compStabilityMeasure(this.frameIjList, this.frameIkList, SysConsts.STABILITY_MEASURE_TOKEN);
this.setTrackingRepValue(this.compTrackingRep(this.frameIjList, this.frameIkList, SysConsts.TRACKING_REPEATABILITY_TOKEN));
this.setViewPntRepValue(this.compViewPntRep(this.frameIjList, this.frameIkList, SysConsts.VIEWPOINT_REPEATABILITY_TOKEN));
```

**compStabilityMeasure method implementation**:

```
private void compStabilityMeasure(ArrayList<Mat> frameIjList, ArrayList<Mat>   
frameIkList, String token) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    synchronized (frameIjList) {
        synchronized (frameIjList) {
            this.setRepValue(this.compRep(frameIjList, frameIkList, token));
            this.setSymRepValue(this.compSymRep(this.getRepValue(), frameIkList, frameIjList, token));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at using "thenCombineAsync", eg:

```
    CompletableFuture<String> firstFuture = firstMethod();
    CompletableFuture<String> secondFuture = secondMethod();
    CompletableFuture<String> thirdFuture = thirdMethod();
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> allCompleted = firstFuture
            .thenCombineAsync(secondFuture, (first, second) -> listOf(first, second))
            .thenCombineAsync(thirdFuture, (list, third) -> {
                list.add(third);
                return list;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `allOf`, and then create a `CompletableFuture` that gets completed with a Stream containing the results of your individual CompletableFutures:

```
CompletableFuture<String> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "hi1");
CompletableFuture<String> cf2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "hi2");

List<CompletableFuture<String>> cfsList = Arrays.asList(cf1, cf2);
CompletableFuture<Void> allCfs = CompletableFuture.allOf((CompletableFuture<String>[]) cfsList.toArray());
CompletableFuture<Stream<String>> cfWithFinishedStream = allCfs.thenApply((allCf) -> 
              cfsList.stream().map(cf -> cf.getNow("")));
```

Example to get the values from the stream when the CF completes:

```
    cfWithFinishedStream.thenAccept(stream -> 
           stream.forEach(string -> System.out.println(string)));
```

If you don't like streams, you can convert them to a List using collect:

```
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> cfWithFinishedList = allCfs
            .thenApply((allCf) -> 
              cfsList.stream().map(cf -> 
                       cf.getNow("")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```